# SELECT only those columns, where values are NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a SELECT statment (using a function), which returns 60 columns and about 10000 rows.
Some of these columns only contain NULL values - I want to exclude them from the selection. Is there any way to do this?

The query is a bit complicated, including a tablfunc function, but the results are very nice:

```
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
 ID     |column1| column2| ...     |column60 | 
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
 1      | 1     | NULL   | 52.5    | 15      |
 ...    | ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     |
 10000  | 2     | NULL   | 87.5    | 3       |
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
```

In this case I don't want to select column2.

The query is:

```
  select * from dma.ct_fafajkod_pont
  ('select a.pont, a.faj, a.tom from 
         (select 
                    f.ppont_azon pont,
                    fl.mezonev faj,
                    case WHEN f.tom08::integer=1 then 2.5 WHEN f.tom08::integer=2 then 12.5 WHEN f.tom08::integer=3 then 35 WHEN tom08::integer=4 then 75 else 0 END +
                    case WHEN f.tom920::integer=1 then 2.5 WHEN f.tom920::integer=2 then 12.5 WHEN f.tom920::integer=3 then 35 WHEN tom920::integer=4 then 75 else 0 END +
                    case WHEN f.tom2135::integer=1 then 2.5 WHEN f.tom2135::integer=2 then 12.5 WHEN f.tom2135::integer=3 then 35 WHEN tom2135::integer=4 then 75 else 0 END +
                    case WHEN f.tom3650::integer=1 then 2.5 WHEN f.tom3650::integer=2 then 12.5 WHEN f.tom3650::integer=3 then 35 WHEN tom3650::integer=4 then 75 else 0 END +
                    case WHEN f.tom51::integer=1 then 2.5 WHEN f.tom51::integer=2 then 12.5 WHEN f.tom51::integer=3 then 35 WHEN tom51::integer=4 then 75 else 0 END tom
                    from field.fafaj f, field.fafajlista fl where f.fajnev=fl.fafaj_kulcs ) a
            order by 1,2', 
  'select distinct fl.mezonev from field.fafajlista fl order by 1');
```

Comment: how can we help on your query if you hide it?

Comment: Are you trying to make this work dynamically? As in, if a column is entirely null, ignore it on the fly, but if a value is added to that column, it returns that entire column?

Comment: Guildsbounty:

That's correct.

Comment: Thr query is not a secret, I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly specify the columns to select, like:

```
SELECT ID, column1 FROM table;
```

Or you could do as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1958) and select the columns directly from the schema and exclude the ones you don't want:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT 'o' || '.' || c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns As c
            WHERE table_name = 'officepark' 
            AND  c.column_name NOT IN('officeparkid', 'contractor')
    ), ',') || ' FROM officepark As o' As sqlstmt
```

**edit:** After reading [guildsbounty's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425614/select-only-those-columns-where-values-are-not-null/26425767#comment41496219_26425614), I realise this answer isn't going to help if you want to do it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, but I do want it to do it dynamically. I also can't edit functions - but in that case this would probably help.